# PyQt5 TypeError for openPersitentEditor

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Hi everyone so I was doing some exam prep with PYQT5 and I created an application from an exercise in my workbook where we have to make it display a list of courses and when you click them it opens a message box with the course name also there is a button so that the user can add a course to the list. The add button is suppoused to open a QlineEdit on the last item in the listWidget, so the user can edit the field however I keep getting a TypeError message:

line 67, in onAddButton
self.mylistWidget.openPersistentEditor(self, modelItem)
TypeError: openPersistentEditor(self, QListWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'UNISACourses'

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QListWidget, QLineEdit, QWidget, QMessageBox, QHBoxLayout, QAbstractItemView,
                             QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QButtonGroup)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtGui


class MyListWidget(QListWidget, QLineEdit, QWidget):
    """
    Subclassed QListWidget to allow for the closing of open editors and other modifications
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            print("Closing any persistent editor")
            self.closePersistentEditor(self.model().index(self.count() - 1))
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)


class UNISACourses(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # Main Window Settings
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Courses')

        # Layout
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        # Main Widget
        self.mylistWidget = MyListWidget()
        self.mylistWidget.addItems(["COS1511", "COS1521", "COS1512", "MNB1512", "INF1505", "FAC1502"])
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.mylistWidget)

        # Define a layout for the other buttons to exist in for flexibility with resizing
        self.btn_add = QPushButton("Add", clicked=self.onAddButton)
        self.btn_delete = QPushButton("Delete", clicked=self.onDeleteButton)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.btn_add)
        hbox.addWidget(self.btn_delete)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(hbox)

        # Define any additional behavior of the list
        self.mylistWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self, item):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Info", item.text())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onAddButton(self):
        """
        Opens a QLineEdit editor on the last item in the listwidget, allowing the user to edit the field.
        NOTE: The user must click outside of the editor field then press Enter in order to close the editor
        """
        self.mylistWidget.addItem('')
        modelItem = self.mylistWidget.model().index(self.mylistWidget.count() - 1)
        self.mylistWidget.openPersistentEditor(self, modelItem)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onDeleteButton(self):
        for item in self.mylistWidget.selectedItems():
            self.mylistWidget.takeItem(self.mylistWidget.row(item))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = UNISACourses()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing two incorrect arguments (`self` and a QModelIndex) to `QListWidget.openPersistentEditor` which accepts *one* QListWidgetItem. Use the `QListWidget.item` method to get the item. You can also add `QListWidget.setCurrentItem` so it gets selected right away and ready to edit.

```
def onAddButton(self):
    self.mylistWidget.addItem('')
    modelItem = self.mylistWidget.item(self.mylistWidget.count() - 1)
    self.mylistWidget.openPersistentEditor(modelItem)
    self.mylistWidget.setCurrentItem(modelItem)
```

Same fix here:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
        print("Closing any persistent editor")
        self.closePersistentEditor(self.item(self.count() - 1))
    else:
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

Also the Qt Namespace class for `Qt.Key_Return` is inside the QtCore Module.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, Qt
from PyQt5 import QtGui
```